# Split a bibliography into (alphabetical) groups of authors

Tags: biblatex, sorting

**EDIT: I've simplified and clarified the question**

I am working on a very large bibliography (500+ entries) with the default `nty` sorting: `(sort)author` - `title` - `date`. I would like to single out one or more authors with a title or (pseudo)sectioning command.

> Aristotle, *Title*...
> Cicero, *Title*...
> ___   **Immanuel Kant**
> Kant, I., *Title*...
> Kant, I., *Title*...
> Knuth, D.E., *Title*...
> ___   **Friedrich Nietzsche**
> Nietzsche, F., *Title*...

Does `biblatex` have tools to do that?
Either by

1. printing *one bibliography*, but with a mechanism that can **recognize the first entry by a certain (sort)author** and print an arbitrary element right before it?
2. putting a filter in place that sorts my entries into **alphabetical segments** (`sortauthor` is A-Kans, Kant-Nietzschd, Nietzsche-Z) and then using that filter to print *several partial bibliographies*? (Each prefaced by the appropriate `printnote` or `heading`.)

My attempts so far have been of this second kind. Now I can easily write a `SourceMap` that checks whether the author **is exactly** Kant or Nietzsche:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
\maps[datatype=bibtex]{ 
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=author, match={Kant, Immanuel}, final]
    \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={by-kant}]
    }
}}
```

But I haven't find a way to create a filter that can tell whether the author **is between** Kant and Nietzsche alphabetically, or before Kant:

```
\step[fieldsource=sortauthor, alphabetizebefore={Kant, Immanuel}],
```

Does `biblatex` have a built-in option or formula that checks for (strict) *alphabetic ordering*?

I would strongly prefer not to have to build a chain of regular expressions, as it would be laborious:

> % Check if strictly between "Kant" and "Nietzsche"
> IF ((first letter is L-M)
> OR (first letter = K AND second letter is B-Z)
> OR (second letter = A AND third letter is O-Z)
> OR (third letter = N AND fourth letter is U-Z))
> OR ((first letter = N AND second letter is A-H)
> OR (second letter = I AND third letter is A-D)
> OR (third letter = E AND fourth letter is A-S)
> ... OR (...))

and subject to possible pitfalls (uncertainties in sorting when names contain characters that aren't strictly alphabetic, as in "D'Alembert").

Surely, there must be a way to *access the same native mechanism* by which `sortauthor`s are compared and ordered in the .bbl output? And put it to use in filtering/splitting the output?

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%\DeclareSourcemap{     % How to implement this?
%\maps[datatype=bibtex]{    
%  \map{
%    \step[fieldsource=sortauthor, alphabetizebefore={Kant, Immanuel}]  % How?
%    \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={before-kant}]
%    }
%}}
%\DeclareSourcemap{     % How to implement this?
%\maps[datatype=bibtex]{    
%  \map{
%    \step[fieldsource=sortauthor, alphabetizeafter={Kant, Immanuel}]   % How?
%    \step[fieldsource=sortauthor, alphabetizebefore={Nietzsche, Friedrich}]    % How?
%    \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={before-nietzsche}]
%    }
%}}
%\DeclareSourcemap{     % How to implement this?
%\maps[datatype=bibtex]{    
%  \map{
%    \step[fieldsource=sortauthor, alphabetizeafter={Nietzsche, Friedrich}] % How?
%    \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={after-nietzsche}]
%    }
%}}

\defbibnote{by-kant}{\bfseries Kant}
\defbibnote{by-nietzsche}{\bfseries Nietzsche}

\begin{document}

Authors before Kant.
\cite{aristotle:anima}, \cite{cicero}

Kant
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}

Authors before Nietzsche
\cite{knuth:ct:a}

Nietzsche
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}

\section*{Split bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword=before-kant,heading=none]
\printbibliography[keyword=before-nietzsche,heading=none,prenote=by-kant]
\printbibliography[keyword=after-nietzsche,heading=none,prenote=by-nietzsche]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible if the bib file can be preprocessed with the help of some external tools. Given a bib file, Python can be used to determine the author names and sort the entries accordingly. Then, the information is passed from Python to LaTeX using biblatex's *category* feature.

The source code for main components are shown here. For complete source code, see https://github.com/xziyue/latex-auto-categorized-bib.

### Explanation

- The Python script analyzes the bibliography file and generate an output file for LaTeX to read. The [output file](https://github.com/xziyue/latex-auto-categorized-bib/blob/master/test-bibinfo.tex) will look like this:

  ```latex
  ...
  \BibAuthorInfo{google-llc}{android_formats}
  \BibAuthorInfo{greenwald-j}{greenwald_2019}
  \BibAuthorInfo{grinstein-eric}{grinstein2018audio}
  \BibAuthorInfo{grobman-s}{grobman_2019}
  \BibAuthorInfo{gu-quanquan}{gu2011linear}
  \BibAuthorInfo{guan-haiying}{guan2019mfc}
  ...
  \BibAllAuthors{adobe-inc,almutairi-zaynab,altinisik-enes,apple-inc,avidemux-contributors,ba-lei-jimmy,bansal-vipin,bartusiak-r-emily,bayram-sevinc,bestagini-paolo,bhagtani-kratika,bharati-a,bianchi-tiziano,...}
  ```

  It includes the bib items associated with each author, as well as an author list that is sorted based on names.
- On the LaTeX side, if `--shell-escape` is enabled, the Python script can be called automatically when compiling. Otherwise, the user can also manually run the Python script (if the bib file does not change frequently). In the example, the Python script is run automatically and the output is read back.

  ```latex
  \immediate\write18{python3 bib_categorizer.py \jobname-bibinfo.tex example.bib}
  % load the generate file
  \input{\jobname-bibinfo.tex}
  ```
- The `\BibAuthorInfo` will create a new category for each author name.
- The user can use `\PrintBibBetween` command to print bib items between two authors in the sorted list. In the example, `\PrintBibBetween{ito-keith}{kabir-mohsin-muhammad}` is used.

#### LaTeX source (test.tex)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \BibAuthorInfo #1#2
{
    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}
    \addtocategory{#1}{#2}
}

\clist_new:N \g_bibinfo_all_authors_clist
\clist_new:N \l_bibinfo_tmp_clist
\cs_new:Npn \BibAllAuthors #1
{
    \clist_gset:Nn \g_bibinfo_all_authors_clist {#1}
}


\bool_new:N \l_bibinfo_start_found_bool
\bool_new:N \l_bibinfo_end_found_bool
\bool_new:N \l_bibinfo_loop_end_bool
\tl_new:N \l_bibinfo_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bibinfo_tmpb_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bibinfo_tmpc_tl
\cs_new:Npn \PrintBibBetween #1#2
{
    \clist_set_eq:NN \l_bibinfo_tmp_clist \g_bibinfo_all_authors_clist
    \bool_set_false:N \l_bibinfo_start_found_bool
    \bool_set_false:N \l_bibinfo_end_found_bool
    \bool_set:Nn \l_bibinfo_loop_end_bool {\clist_if_empty_p:N \l_bibinfo_tmp_clist}

    \bool_until_do:nn {\l_bibinfo_loop_end_bool}
    {
        \clist_pop:NN \l_bibinfo_tmp_clist \l_bibinfo_tmpa_tl
        \exp_args:NV \str_if_eq:nnT  \l_bibinfo_tmpa_tl {#1}
        {
            \bool_set_true:N \l_bibinfo_start_found_bool
        }
        \exp_args:NV \str_if_eq:nnT \l_bibinfo_tmpa_tl {#2}
        {
            \bool_set_true:N \l_bibinfo_end_found_bool
        }
        \bool_if:nT {\l_bibinfo_start_found_bool}
        {
            \tl_set:Nx \l_bibinfo_tmpc_tl {\exp_not:N\printbibliography[category={\l_bibinfo_tmpa_tl},heading=none]}
            \tl_use:N \l_bibinfo_tmpc_tl
        }
        \bool_set:Nn \l_bibinfo_loop_end_bool {\clist_if_empty_p:N \l_bibinfo_tmp_clist || \l_bibinfo_end_found_bool}
    }

    \bool_if:nF {\l_bibinfo_start_found_bool}
    {
        \GenericError{}{Cannot found bib start item "#1"}{}{}
    }

    \bool_if:nF {\l_bibinfo_end_found_bool}
    {
        \GenericError{}{Cannot found bib end item "#2"}{}{}
    }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff


% make sure --shell-escape is enabled (if you want this process to be done automatically when compiling in LaTeX)
% call Python script to process bibliography files
% if there are more than one file, append to the argument list
\immediate\write18{python3 bib_categorizer.py \jobname-bibinfo.tex example.bib}
% load the generate file
\input{\jobname-bibinfo.tex}

\begin{document}

Is is working?

\nocite{*}

\PrintBibBetween{ito-keith}{kabir-mohsin-muhammad}


\end{document}
```

#### Python script (bib_categorizer.py)

The Python script requires `bibtexparser` package.

```python
import bibtexparser
import sys
import os
import re
import string

assert len(sys.argv) >= 3, 'invalid number of arguments'
output_filename = sys.argv[1]
input_filenames = sys.argv[2:]


# only allow certain characters in names
def clean_name_segments(s:str)->str:
    new_s = ''
    cand = string.ascii_letters + ' '
    for c in s:
        if c in cand:
            new_s += c

    return new_s

# return a list of authors
# each author name is represented using a list, where name segments are ordered from first name to last name
def process_author_names(s:str)->list:
    s = s.strip()

    braces_match = re.match('\{(.*)\}', s)
    if braces_match:
        return [[clean_name_segments(braces_match.group(1))]]
    
    ret = []

    parts = s.split(' and ')
    for part in parts:
        if ',' in part:
            last, _, first = part.partition(',')
            ret.append(first.split(' ') + [last])
        else:
            ret.append(part.split(' '))

    for item in ret:
        new_item = [clean_name_segments(x.strip()) for x in item]
        new_item = [x for x in new_item if x]
        item.clear()
        item.extend(new_item)

    return ret
    

def get_author_sort_key(e:list):
    return tuple(map(lambda x: x.lower(), reversed(e)))

author_lut = dict()

for fn in input_filenames:
    assert os.path.exists(fn), f'input file "{fn}" does not exist'

    with open(fn) as f:
        bib = bibtexparser.load(f)
    
    for entry in bib.entries:
        entry_name = entry['ID']

        if 'author' not in entry:
            print(f'Entry {entry_name} does not have author field, it is skipped')
            continue
        
        authors = process_author_names(entry['author'].replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n', ' '))

        # sort based on first author
        first_author_key = get_author_sort_key(authors[0])
        if first_author_key not in author_lut:
            author_lut[first_author_key] = []

        author_lut[first_author_key].append(entry_name)

author_sorted = sorted(list(author_lut.keys()))

output_lines = []
author_name_ids = []
for ind, author_name_seg in enumerate(author_sorted):
    author_bib_items = author_lut[author_name_seg]
    author_name_id = (' '.join(author_name_seg)).replace(' ', '-')
    author_name_ids.append(author_name_id)
    output_lines.append(r'\BibAuthorInfo{%s}{%s}' % (author_name_id, ','.join(author_bib_items)))

output_lines.append('\BibAllAuthors{%s}' % ','.join(author_name_ids))

with open(output_filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(output_lines))
```

#### Improved author sorting

```python
def get_author_sort_key(e:list):
    ret = [x.lower() for x in e]
    if len(ret) <= 2:
        return tuple(reversed(ret))
    else:
        ret_ = [ret[-1]] + [[ret[0]] + ret[1:-1]
        return tuple(ret_)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but there's a small hitch: The current script parses names strictly from right to left; when there's a middle name, it creates a string `Family-Middle-Given`. One would expect `Family-Given-Middle1(-Middle2 etc.)`. As it stands, the alphabetization is sometimes wrong: `\BibAuthorInfo{roosevelt-eleanor}` comes *after* `\BibAuthorInfo{roosevelt-delano-franklin}`, even though "Eleanor" < "Franklin". -- As it happens, my use case is affected (my author has both a middle name, and a brother), so this is directly relevant...

Comment: Can you try the new `get_author_sort_key` function?